# How can I convert from a SQL recursive hierarchical relational table to Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a table with 2 recursive fields PersonID and FollowPersonID that stores all the relations between persons (Person 1  follow Person 2, Person 2 follow Person 1) and I would like to extract and create the associated network in neo4J. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That table (I'll call it "Follows") can be turned into a `FOLLOWS` relationship between two `Person` nodes.

You should be able to use some [APOC procedures for loading using JDBC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_jdbc) to help you do this.

Here is an example:

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root", "Follows") YIELD row
MATCH (p1:Person {id: row.PersonId}), (p2:Person {id: row.FollowPersonId})
MERGE (p1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p2);
```

If that table is large (or there are a lot of `Person` nodes), it would also make sense to first create an index (or uniqueness constraint) on `Person(id)` to speed up the import:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id);
```

If you create the index, this form of the query should ensure the index is used (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897104/974731) for some more details):

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root", "Follows") YIELD row
WITH row.PersonId AS id1, row.FollowPersonId AS id2
MATCH (p1:Person {id: id1}), (p2:Person {id: id2})
USING INDEX p1:Person(id)
USING INDEX p2:Person(id)
MERGE (p1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p2);
```

Comment: From your previous answer on another question, wouldn't the MATCHes not be able to use indexes for lookup? Wouldn't you have to alias row properties into their own values to take advantage of the index?

Comment: I have updated that other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40897104/974731) with more info. The query in my answer *may* cause the planner to use the index for one or both `MATCH` patterns. But currently there seems to be a bug that prevents you from specifying the `USING INDEX` hint unless you use the workaround mentioned in my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ways to connect to your database, then you can use APOC to connect and retrieve data, e.g with following steps

```
CALL apoc.load.driver('your_jdbc_driver');
CALL apoc.load.jdbc( url, 'SELECT PersonID, FollowPersonID FROM PersonFollow;' )
```

and then you can create all nodes and relationships, if you use MERGE. For example like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.PersonID IS UNIQUE;

with "your_jdbc_url" as url
CALL apoc.load.jdbc( url, 'SELECT PersonID, FollowPersonID 
FROM PersonFollow;' ) YIELD row
MERGE (p:Person {PersonID:row.PersonID})
MERGE (f:Person {PersonID:row.FollowPersonID})
CREATE (p)-[:FOLLOWS]->(f)
```

MERGE allows to have also different actions with ON CREATE and ON MATCH , so it's possible to set values of other attributes, depending on existence of the node, or if it is a new node

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried directly from a file and it it worked for a few rows...
but when I have a lot of rows in the file it starts thinking and thinking. 
Not sure I understand how can I create the index from the file? - I am really new. 

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:\\collab1.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Person {PersonId:row.EntityID})
MERGE (f:Person {PersonID:row.ownerEntityID , EnterpriseID:row.EnterpriseId})
CREATE (p)-[:FOLLOWS]->(f)

Comment: Direct Neo4j to commit portions of data. Put USING PERIODIC COMMIT right before the LOAD CSV. More importantly use node labels, relationship-types and property-names consistently - they are case sensitive! PersonID and PersonId are different! Do you consider PersonId unique in your data set? If yes, create constraint like in my answer before. Do that before load statement. Also, MERGE is looking for all properties you specified. Your 1st MERGE tries to find Person by PersonId, 2nd one is trying to find Person that has 2 properties (PersonID and EnterpriseID). Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Without knowing your data it is hard to guess, but here is one example:

Comment: Without knowing your data it is hard to guess what it represents. 
It seems like ownerEntityID and EnterpriseId are someway associated with each other, so
here is one example based really on guess:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/collab1.csv' AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (p:Person {PersonId:row.EntityID})
MERGE (f:Person {PersonId:row.ownerEntityID}) ON CREATE set f.EnterpriseId = row.EnterpriseID
CREATE (p)-[:FOLLOWS]->(f)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks for your help.